# Alpine js setting data from external js

Tags: alpine.js

I'm trying to show a modal by changing the data from an external javascript file after a successful call to the Api, here's what I've tried:

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" x-data="modalData()">
    <div class="modal" x-show="open">
      <div class="modal-content rounded overflow-hidden shadow bg-white" id="modal-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
function modalData() {
  return {
    open: false,
    closeModal () {
      this.open = false;
    },
    openModal () {
      console.log('This gets logged just fine');
      this.open = true;
    }
  }
}
```

And in the successfull ajax call I'm trying to do:

```
modalData().openModal();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that every call to modalData() will create a new object. If you want it to be the same object every time then assign it to a global variable first if that global is not already set, then return that global variable instead

Answer (score 4):

It's a little bit *hacky* solution, but you can use the `_x_dataStack` attribute to access the element data from the external script:

```
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal-wrapper')
modal._x_dataStack[0].openModal()
```

It uses an internal API (tested on 3.8), so it may wont work in the future. A less hacky way would be using a store and mutate the state via e.g. `window.Alpine.store('open', true)`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I have found to send data to alpine components is via custom events. You can declare a function something like this:

```
function ui_update( target, data ){
    var evt = new CustomEvent(target, data);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

And then listen for it in your modal:

```
<div x-data="{message: ''}" @set-modal-message.window="message = $event.detail.message">
    <span x-text="message"></span>
</div>
```

And finally in a script-tag anywhere do:

```
<script>

ui_update('set-modal-message', { detail: { message: 'This is my new message' } } );

</script>
```

Some additional notes. ui_update() is a vanilla javascript function that can be called from anywhere unlike Alpines $dispatch which can only be called from within Alpine-components (with x-data attribute).

By using .window on @set-modal-message the events can be sent from anywhere.

It would be really useful to be able to do Alpine('id of alpine component tag').something() but as far as I can tell that is not possible.

To accomplish something like that you have to declare an Alpine store from within the 'alpine:init' event on the document which you component can access and use.

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    console.log('Alpine.js init.');
    
    Alpine.store('modal', {
        name: '', // must be defined and unique for each modal component
        is_open: false,

        show(name){
            this.name = name;
            this.is_open = true;
        },
        hide(){
            this.is_open = false;
        },
        isActive(name){
            return this.name == name && this.is_open;
        },
    });

});
```

You can then declare an Alpine component to use it like this:

```
<script>

function messageDialogComponent(){
    return {
        name: 'dialog-message',
        message: '',
    };
}

</script>
<div x-cloak
    x-data="messageDialogComponent()"
    x-show="$store.modal.isActive(name)"
    @open-modal-message.window="$store.modal.show(name); message = $event.detail.message"
    @click="$store.modal.hide()"
    class="page-overlay">
    
    <div id="dialog-message" @click.stop="">
        <div>
            <a @click.prevent="$store.modal.hide()" href="#">✖</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p x-text="message" class="text-center">Message</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button @click.stop="$store.modal.hide()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```
Alpine.store('modal').show('name-of-your-modal');
```

and

```
Alpine.store('modal').hide();
```